# C# equivalent for ruby's string successor method ("abcd".succ -> "abce")

Tags: c#

Does C# have an equivalent to [Ruby's string successor method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-next)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no built-in equivalent, although of course you can create your own. I'd suggest the skeleton of something like this:

```
char[] array = text.ToArray();
// Perform mutation...
// - find last alphanumeric character, and work backwards from that...
// - or go from final character if there aren't any alphanumerics
return new string(array);
```

Personally I think I'd want rather more restricted semantics personally, with a specific set of characters to use. The description given in the Ruby docs seems to be along the lines of "we'll work with anything" rather than failing if you're trying to do something which doesn't really make sense. I certainly wouldn't want to increment some arbitrary UTF-16 code unit when I was expecting A-Z, 0-9.

Comment: I read the docs and got the strange feeling that someone had nothing better to do.  Will Ruby become the next PHP ?